# Opening up https proxy port on google cloud platform

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm building a simple web app (MEAN) and deploying to GCP (Google Cloud Platform) I have built an application where my client runs on 4200 and the server runs on port 3000. I have two choices, combine my client and server to run on the same port, or simply allow the connection between 4200 and 3000.  Currently, I get an error trying to proxy requests between these two ports. Any ideas how I open 3000 so 4200 can talk to it?

Comment: You are using an instance in Compute Engine, right?

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting?  Have you looked to see if it's related to a firewall configuration [1] issue?                                        
 [1]: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls